# Word for a "cell" in a 3×3 matrix

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, mathematics

In a 2×2 matrix the intersection of a single row and column can be referred to as a *quadrant*.  Is there a corresponding or more general term for a 3×3 matrix?

Comment: Personally I like "cell".  :-)

Comment: @Hellion Yeah, I wasn't sure if that was a spreadsheet-specific term though.  I couldn't find any references that suggest *cell* is appropriate for a general table or matrix.

Comment: I'm not going to trawl through the Google results: you can do that yourself. There are many. Perhaps there's an authoritative example; here's a generic one: 'You can generate values algorithmically to fill the cells of a matrix.'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Sorry, I meant *authoritative* references.  I can find a lot of Google results that use *there* as a possessive pronoun, but that doesn't make it correct.

Comment: Look this up: Criminology Research Focus - Page 17 - Google Books Result
https://books.google.co.uk/books?isbn=1600218822
Karen T. Froeling - 2007 - ‎Criminologie
The column totals at the last row of the matrix represent fn,f2l, ,fk\ for the first k ... -TM and the command input into the cell for row 2 and column l of the matrix ... Third, sort the column order according to the column sums in ascending order.

Comment: I was about to ask this very same question today :)

Answer (score 2):

How about an **element**? According to [mathwords](http://www.mathwords.com/e/element_of_a_matrix.htm):

> *Element* is an entry in a matrix. Its address is given by row and column number.

Comment: Hmm, that's a good one.  Also from this site I see that an element of a 2x2x2 cube is an [octant](http://www.mathwords.com/o/octants.htm) :)

Comment: No; that's the term for the item occupying that position. The position itself is a cell.

Comment: Please don't make people click through to a justification (the link might die). Please include the justification in your answer, and use the link along with plain-text to provide the citation.

Answer (score 0):

> The individual items in a matrix are called [its *elements* or *entries*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_%28mathematics%29).

But everyone I know calls them "cells", because of Excel.

And *quadrant* refers to a subspace of a Cartesian space, consisting of all points lying on the same side of all axes.  In 2-space, the "lower right" quadrant consists of all points below the x-axis and to the right of the y-axis.  In 3-space, such a subspace should be called an "octant", but isn't.

Comment: You're failing to distinguish position and the item occupying that position with 'element' = 'entry'.

Comment: For a given matrix, the position uniquely defines the value in that position.  I suppose you could talk about cell in any of several matrices...

Comment: But OP is obviously focusing on the geometrical feature rather than the information stored at that location.

Answer (score 0):

In the game *tic tac toe*, the grid positions are typically referred to as ***spaces***, or ***squares***.

> **Tic-tac-toe** (also known as **Noughts and crosses** or **Xs and Os**) is a paper-and-pencil game for two players, X and O, who take turns marking the ***spaces*** in a 3×3 grid.
>   ...
>   The first player, who shall be designated "X", has 3 possible positions to mark during the first turn. Superficially, it might seem that there are 9 possible positions, corresponding to the 9 ***squares*** in the grid. However, by rotating the board, we will find that in the first turn, every corner mark is strategically equivalent to every other corner mark.
>   <sub>[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tic-tac-toe)</sub>

*Squares* is also used to refer to the positions on a chessboard/checkerboard.